# $\mathbb{R}\mathbb{P^2}$ as a quotient space

Tags: general-topology

If we construct  $\mathbb{R}\mathbb{P^2}$  by gluing the sides of $I^2$, can anyone explain for me that why $\mathbb{R}\mathbb{P^2}$ can be considered as the quotient space induced by the equivalence relation $a\sim-a$ on $S^2$?

Comment: Look at the ways you glue the sides, and deform the square into a disk.

Answer (score 3):

$$ \times \times \times $$
**Disclaimer:** I'll give an informal description, to help visualization. For details just look in every basic geometry book.

$$ \times \times \times $$
Start considering the set of lines which pass thought the origin in $\mathbb{R}^3$. You want to consider every line as a point, and mathematically speaking you do this considering $\mathbb{R}^3 \setminus (0,0,0)$, and the quotient of it with the usual equivalence that identifies every point which lies in a line as above.

We pick as a representative of a generic line $s$ the point $x \in s$ such that $\| x \|=1$.

Note that in this way we are considering $S^2$ (by definition!) **but also** we have two times the points needed. In fact, every line meets $S^2$ in two antipodal points, $a, -a$ (they have the same norm!) **which we want to be the same point** because they lie in the same line.

[image]

So we can represent $\mathbb{RP}^2$ as $S^2$ with antipodal points identified.

Comment: thank you Riccardo , but can u pls help me with writing this solution explicitly?because it is a homework.

Comment: @user115608 well if you "by explicitly" mean writing down an homeomorphism between the two sets. it is not "immediate". My idea shows you a bijection, then if you consider your space equipped with the quotient topology with a few calculation you should show that it is in fact an homeomorphism between RP2 and this S^2 quotiented. I don't have time to write down calculations, but I'm more than happy to revise your work or help if you are stuck somewhere :)